# php explode and foreach returens only one loop

Tags: php, foreach, explode

I am not very professional but 
I have this PHP code :

```
$m = mysqli_query($dblink,"select * from bot where type='movie' and ID ='$wait'");
while($a = mysqli_fetch_array($m, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

    $ex = explode(",",$a["links"]);
    preg_match_all('/\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i',  $ex[1], $matches);
    $urls = $matches[0];
    foreach($urls as $url){
        $s=size($url); 
    }
    preg_match_all('/\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i', $ex[1], $matches2);
    $urls2 = $matches2[0]; 
}
```

and I also have `http://site1.com,http://site2.com,http://site3.com` in my "links" column of database.

so here is my problem : the code only shows one of the sites.
I was wondering if the problem is with foreach or explode or non of them?

thank all of you in advance!

**EDIT :**
so I changed my code to this :

```
$ex = explode(",",$a["links"]);

$url=$a["links"];
foreach($ex as $url){
    $s=size($url); 
    ...
}
```

and it seems to be a problem with `$url` because when I use a custom url for example `http://test.com` instead of `$url` it works and shows me 3 links which is the number of links in my database with the url of `http://test.com`.
What am I doing wrong with `$url` ?

Comment: You're only calling `preg_match_all()` on `$ex[1]`, not all the links that `explode()` returned.

Comment: As I understand there is no point of `explode()`. You can use `$a['links']` in `preg_match_all()` instead of `$ex[1]`

Comment: Or just use `$ex`, you don't need to call `preg_match_all()`.

Comment: thanks for quick response. I changed $ex[1] to $ex[0] . the size function is now working. it returnes another site but still returning only one. @Barmar

Comment: You need to do all the elements of `$ex`, not just one. Use a `foreach` loop.

Comment: `foreach ($ex as $url)`

Comment: ok, I did this, as I said I have 3 links in my database. it returens 2 links linke this : 1- http://site1.com  and 2- http://site2.com,http://site3.com @BorisDiádus

Comment: I am sorry as I said I'm not very professional in PHP , could you please modify my code ? I would appreciate it @Barmar

Comment: Someone already posted an answer

Comment: I edited my question, would you mind taking a look ? @Barmar

Comment: That looks like it should work. What does the `size()` function do?

Comment: Could there be spaces around the commas in the database? Try using `size(trim($url))`

Comment: it checks the links size (for downlaod links) , and no there is no spaces . used size(trim($url)) but nothing changed @Barmar

Comment: is it possible it links all 3 urls into one text for example and it causes some errors ?

Answer (score 1):

```
 $ex = explode(",",$a["links"]);
```

Will return an array of values (links) as follows:

```
$ex[0] = 'http://site1.com'
$ex[1] = 'http://site2.com'
$ex[2] = 'http://site3.com'
```

And you are passing only the second position of the array (index = 1 => $ex[1]) to the next line

```
preg_match_all('/\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i',  $ex[1], $matches);
```

so, you can do this:

```
foreach($ex as $url) {
    preg_match_all('/\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i',  $url, $matches);
}
```

to get the matches for each url in the links database column

Comment: thnak you for the response , I did what you say but the code is not working now!